# create BigQuery external tables partitioned by one/multiple columns

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am porting a java application from Hadoop/Hive to Google Cloud/BigQuery. The application writes avro files to hdfs and then creates Hive external tables with one/multiple partitions on top of the files.
I understand Big Query only supports date/timestamp partitions for now, and no nested partitions.

The way we now handle hive is that we generate the ddl and then execute it with a rest call.

I could not find support for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in the BigQuery DDL docs, so I've switched to using the java library.
I managed to create an external table, but I cannot find any reference to partitions in the parameters passed to the call.
Here's a snippet of the code I use:

```
....
ExternalTableDefinition extTableDef = 
ExternalTableDefinition.newBuilder(schemaName, null, FormatOptions.avro()).build();
TableId tableID = TableId.of(dbName, tableName);
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableID, extTableDef).build();
Table table = bigQuery.create(tableInfo);   
....
```

There is however support for partitions for non external tables.

I have a few questions questions:

- is there support for creating external tables with partition(s)? Can you please point me in the right direction
- is loading the data into BigQuery preferred to having it stored in GS avro files?
- if yes, how would we deal with schema evolution?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot create partitioned tables over files on GCS, although you can use the special [`_FILE_NAME` pseudo-column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#the_file_name_pseudo_column) to filter out the files that you don't want to read.
2. If you can, prefer just to load data into BigQuery rather than leaving it on GCS. [Loading data is free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free), and queries will be way faster than if you run them over Avro files on GCS. BigQuery uses a [columnar format called Capacitor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format) internally, which is heavily optimized for BigQuery, whereas Avro is a row-based format and doesn't perform as well.
3. In terms of schema evolution, if you need to change a column type, drop a column, etc., you should recreate your table (`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ...`). If you are only ever adding columns, you can add the new columns using the API or UI.

See also a [relevant blog post about lazy data loading](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-sql-data-languages-ddl-and-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews).

Comment: Elliot, thank you very much for your answer! Are you planning multiple column and non timestamp partitions for the near future?

Comment: For non timestamp/date-based partitioning, please follow [the relevant feature request on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817). I'm not aware of an existing feature request for partitioning by multiple columns, but you could create one.